# Extracting the radio firmware image from an Android phone

Tags: rom, rom-flashing, fastboot, radio-firmware

How do you pull radio images off an Android device? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This is heavily dependent on the manufacturer and probably the device as well.  You'd be best off making this specific.

Comment: But generally, as not even a nandroid backup cares for the radio, this probably has to be done by creating a dump (dd) from the corresponding partition via ADB -- and thus requires the SDK installed.

Answer (score -1):

You should root your phone and then with an app like Link2SD or even Root Explorer you could get the APK of the Radio app. In fact, with this mode you can get ANY APK of the system.

Link2SD is more intuitive. But if you like the hard way go with Root Explorer and navigate to system/data/app and look for your desired APK

Comment: The question is about pulling the radio firmware image... not a radio app (apk)...